# How to add controls programatically on button click?

Tags: .net, dynamic-controls, multiview

I have a website form (c#) that sits inside a multiview control. The muliview control has 4 steps, so the first 3 steps gather information and if valid move to the next view on button click.

I want to dynamically build the form based on previous answers, but from what I've read so far I'm a little unsure how to make this happen.

For example, on step 1, a user completes some textbox controls and clicks submit.

Based on the data submitted in panel 1, the next panel needs to create a number of controls dynamically - some labels, some textboxes.

As this click is after both the init and page_load, I'm unsure how this will work.

Of course I could create all the label/textbox controls up front and disable them as necessary, but this seems to be quite a poor use of resource.

Bottom line, I'm inexperienced at working with dynamic controls so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you doing with data from second panel, are there any buttons, postbacks etc? If you create controls after OnInit they still are created but postback data will not be autoset. So if you call postbacks on second panel and you need data from those dynamic controls you need to get this data in OnInit from Request.Forms[dynamicControlClientId] or maybe store this in ViewState. Another problem is do you need to see dynamic controls after postback so you have to store information on second panel how to create controls on postback(conditions from first panel).

Comment: Yes, there will be further postbacks. In all the multiview has 4 steps, so the first 3 will postback when they move onto the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, below i've pasted working example.
Things to be aware of:

- To avoid error

`Message=Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.
Source=System.Web
ErrorCode=-2147467259`

set this property on your dynamic controls

`EnableViewState = false`

Data for this example looks like this

Brand Engine Color Cost
VW, 1.2, Black, 72 000
VW, 1.2, White, 70 000
VW, 1.6 TDI, Red, 79 500
VW, 1.6 TDI, White, 78 800
Ford, 1.6, Black, 57 600
Ford, 1.6, Green, 57 100
Ford, 2.0 TDCi, Black, 87 300
Ford, 2.0 TDCi, White, 86 600

Basicaly this works like this:

- Choose car brand and select button(button is our criteria for generationg controls)
  Ofcourse you can also do logic with drop downs etc.
- On second screen you have one or two drop downs based on your choice
- If you have two drop downs, second is dependant of first drop down's choice, so you have example of dependency and postbacks

Page code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:MultiView ID="mvPanels" runat="server">
    <asp:View ID="vPanel1" runat="server">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pick car</td>
                    <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBrand" runat="server" /></td>
                    <td><asp:Button ID="btnPanel1Next" Text="Next" runat="server" 
                            onclick="btnPanel1Next_Click" /></td>
                    <td><asp:Button ID="btnPanel1NextEngineOnly" Text="Next (pick engine only)" runat="server" 
                            onclick="btnPanel1NextEngineOnly_Click" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="vPanel2" runat="server">
        <%--<table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pick engine</td>
                    <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEngine" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" 
                            onselectedindexchanged="ddlEngine_SelectedIndexChanged" /></td>
                    <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlColor" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" 
                            onselectedindexchanged="ddlColor_SelectedIndexChanged" /></td>
                    <td><asp:Button ID="btnPanel2Prev" Text="Prev" runat="server" 
                            onclick="btnPanel2Prev_Click" /><asp:Button ID="btnPanel2Next" Text="Next" 
                            runat="server" Enabled="False" onclick="btnPanel2Next_Click" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>--%>
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="vPanel3" runat="server">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" /></td>
                    <td><asp:Button ID="btnPanel3Prev" Text="Prev" runat="server" 
                            onclick="btnPanel3Prev_Click" /><asp:Button ID="btnPanel3Finish" 
                            Text="Confirm" runat="server" onclick="btnPanel3Finish_Click" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
</div>
</form>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public class CarConfiguration
    {
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string Engine { get; set; }
        public PaintColor Paint { get; set; }
        public string Cost { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class CarConfigurationFilter
    {
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string Engine { get; set; }
        public PaintColor? Paint { get; set; }
        public bool EngineOnly { get; set; }
    }

    public enum PaintColor
    {
        Black,
        Red,
        White,
        Green,
    }

    public List<CarConfiguration> availableCars = new List<CarConfiguration>
    {
        new CarConfiguration{
            Brand = "VW",
            Engine = "1.2",
            Paint = PaintColor.Black,
            Cost = "72 000",
        },
        new CarConfiguration{
            Brand = "VW",
            Engine = "1.2",
            Paint = PaintColor.White,
            Cost = "70 000",
        },
        new CarConfiguration{
            Brand = "VW",
            Engine = "1.6 TDI",
            Paint = PaintColor.Red,
            Cost = "79 500"
        },
        new CarConfiguration{
            Brand = "VW",
            Engine = "1.6 TDI",
            Paint = PaintColor.White,
            Cost = "78 800",
        },
        new CarConfiguration{
            Brand = "Ford",
            Engine = "1.6",
            Paint = PaintColor.Black,
            Cost = "57 600"
        },
        new CarConfiguration{
            Brand = "Ford",
            Engine = "1.6",
            Paint = PaintColor.Green,
            Cost = "57 100"
        },
        new CarConfiguration{
            Brand = "Ford",
            Engine = "2.0 TDCi",
            Paint = PaintColor.Black,
            Cost = "87 300"
        },
        new CarConfiguration{
            Brand = "Ford",
            Engine = "2.0 TDCi",
            Paint = PaintColor.White,
            Cost = "86 600"
        },
    };

    CarConfigurationFilter filter
    {
        get { return (CarConfigurationFilter)ViewState["Filter"]; }
        set { ViewState["Filter"] = value; }
    }

    //If you have multiview in control you need to create this in event before event PageLoad like  LoadViewState, LoadControlState, LoadControlState
    protected override void OnPreLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack && mvPanels.ActiveViewIndex == 1)
        {
            CreateControlsOnPanel2(true, !filter.EngineOnly);
        }
        base.OnPreLoad(e);
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ddlBrand.DataSource = availableCars.Select(x => x.Brand).Distinct();
            ddlBrand.DataBind();
            filter = new CarConfigurationFilter();
            mvPanels.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
        }
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    protected void btnPanel1Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        filter.Brand = ddlBrand.SelectedValue;
        filter.EngineOnly = false;

        CreateControlsOnPanel2(true, true);

        mvPanels.ActiveViewIndex++; 
    }

    protected void btnPanel1NextEngineOnly_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        filter.Brand = ddlBrand.SelectedValue;
        filter.EngineOnly = true;
        CreateControlsOnPanel2(true, false);

        mvPanels.ActiveViewIndex++; 
    }

    void CreateControlsOnPanel2(bool enginePickerEnabled, bool colorPickerEnabled)
    {
        var btnPanel2Prev = new Button();
        btnPanel2Prev.ID = "btnPanel1Prev";
        btnPanel2Prev.EnableViewState = false;    
        btnPanel2Prev.Text = "Prev";
        btnPanel2Prev.Click += btnPanel2Prev_Click;

        var btnPanel2Next = new Button();
        btnPanel2Next.ID="btnPanel2Next";
        btnPanel2Next.Text = "Next";
        btnPanel2Next.EnableViewState = false;
        btnPanel2Next.Enabled = false;
        btnPanel2Next.Click += btnPanel2Next_Click;


        if (enginePickerEnabled)
        {
            var ddlEngine = new DropDownList();
            ddlEngine.ID = "ddlEngine";
            ddlEngine.AutoPostBack = true;
            ddlEngine.EnableViewState = false;

            var engines = availableCars.Where(x => x.Brand == filter.Brand).Select(found => found.Engine).Distinct().ToList();
            engines.Insert(0, String.Empty);
            ddlEngine.DataSource = engines;
            ddlEngine.DataBind();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Engine))
            {
                ddlEngine.SelectedValue = filter.Engine;
                if (!colorPickerEnabled)
                    btnPanel2Next.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
                ddlEngine.SelectedIndex = 0;
            ddlEngine.SelectedIndexChanged += ddlEngine_SelectedIndexChanged;
            vPanel2.Controls.Add(ddlEngine);
        }
        //remember to add ID to all dynamic controls or there might be an error on postback
        if (colorPickerEnabled)
        {
            var ddlColor = new DropDownList();
            ddlColor.ID = "ddlColor";
            ddlColor.AutoPostBack = true;
            ddlColor.EnableViewState = false;
            ddlColor.SelectedIndexChanged += ddlColor_SelectedIndexChanged;
            vPanel2.Controls.Add(ddlColor);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Engine))
            {
                var colors = availableCars.Where(x => x.Brand == filter.Brand && x.Engine == filter.Engine).Select(found => found.Paint.ToString()).Distinct().ToList();
                colors.Insert(0, String.Empty);
                ddlColor.DataSource = colors;
                if (filter.Paint.HasValue)
                {
                    ddlColor.SelectedValue = filter.Paint.Value.ToString();
                    btnPanel2Next.Enabled = true;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                ddlColor.DataSource = null;
                ddlColor.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            ddlColor.DataBind();
        }

        vPanel2.Controls.Add(btnPanel2Prev);
        vPanel2.Controls.Add(btnPanel2Next);
    }

    protected void ddlEngine_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ddlEngine = sender as DropDownList;
        var btnPanel2Next = (Button)vPanel2.FindControl("btnPanel2Next");

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlEngine.SelectedValue))
        {
            filter.Engine = ddlEngine.SelectedValue;
            var colors = availableCars.Where(x => x.Brand == filter.Brand && x.Engine == filter.Engine).Select(found => found.Paint.ToString()).Distinct().ToList();
            colors.Insert(0, String.Empty);
            filter.Paint = null;

            var ddlColor = (DropDownList)vPanel2.FindControl("ddlColor");
            if (ddlColor != null)
            {
                ddlColor.DataSource = colors;
                ddlColor.DataBind();
                ddlColor.SelectedIndex = 0;

                btnPanel2Next.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
                btnPanel2Next.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            var ddlColor = (DropDownList)vPanel2.FindControl("ddlColor");
            if (ddlColor != null)
            {
                ddlColor.Items.Clear();
                ddlColor.SelectedIndex = -1;
            }
            filter.Engine = null;
            btnPanel2Next.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    protected void ddlColor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ddlColor = (DropDownList)vPanel2.FindControl("ddlColor");
        var btnPanel2Next = (Button)vPanel2.FindControl("btnPanel2Next");

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlColor.SelectedValue))
        {
            filter.Paint = (PaintColor)Enum.Parse(typeof(PaintColor), ddlColor.SelectedValue);
            btnPanel2Next.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            filter.Paint = null;
            btnPanel2Next.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    protected void btnPanel2Prev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        filter.Engine = null;
        filter.Paint = null;
        mvPanels.ActiveViewIndex--;
    }

    protected void btnPanel2Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mvPanels.ActiveViewIndex++;

        var selectedConfiguration = availableCars.Where(x => x.Brand == filter.Brand && x.Engine == filter.Engine
        && (!filter.Paint.HasValue || x.Paint == filter.Paint)).Distinct().FirstOrDefault();
        if (selectedConfiguration != null)
            lblResult.Text = String.Format("You have selected {0} {1} {2} for {3} PLN", selectedConfiguration.Brand,
                selectedConfiguration.Engine, selectedConfiguration.Paint, selectedConfiguration.Cost);
    }

    protected void btnPanel3Prev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mvPanels.ActiveViewIndex--;
        CreateControlsOnPanel2(true, !filter.EngineOnly);

    }

    protected void btnPanel3Finish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

If you have any additional questions I will be glad to help